# Counting outgoing TCP connections filter by domain a application in centOS

Tags: centos, tcp

How can I count outgoing TCP (maybe also UDP) connections to a certain domain in linux machines, in particular centOS.

Comment: Running `tcpdump` with `nohup` could potentially be what you are looking for, such as: `nohup tcpdump port 53` then parse its output. Probably good only if you run this for a specific amount of time, not continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most simplistic form you can do it with iptables

For example below rule will log into /var/log/messages (actually it really depends on your rsyslog.conf or syslog.conf where messages will be logged to) all access to 192.168.0.1

```
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -j LOG --log-level 1 --log-prefix local_access
```

And this is how this will look like in the /var/log/messages

```
Oct 30 06:37:39 ip-10-230-3-20 kernel: local_accessIN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.230.3.20 DST=192.168.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=62738 SEQ=8
```

In case you also need some extra information, like for example process id initiating this connection that would need to be done via either of below

- dtrace if you are on Oracle EL
- systemtap if you are on other Linux distro
- auditd - there is an existing pretty good thread on this here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102926/how-to-interpret-the-saddr-field-of-an-audit-log

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate user per domain, you can setup iptables to log outgoing connections and parse the log afterwards.